# Can Struts 2 handle isValid() methods instead of getValid()

Tags: java, struts2, boolean, ognl

In the Struts2 framework, when I call this code in the JSP:

```
if(test='item.value > 0')
```

It will execute the following Java code:

```
getItem().getValue() > 0
```

Does this framework also allow support for `boolean` attributes? Instead of a `get()` method, they are usually called `"is"`. For example, `public boolean isValid()` instead of `public boolean getValid`. If I do the following struts code:

```
if(test='item.valid')
```

will it call the appropriate `isValid()` method or will it fail to find a `getValid()` method and thus return `null`?

Comment: Have you tried this? You can find if this is working or not by simple trying it. :)

Comment: Do you have both of this methods?

Comment: @Aleksandr I thoguht of this question at a point where I don't have a project with struts2 framework ready to launch. Google is also no help because there is no real keyword to search for (is vs. get?) and thus all results are irrelevant. Please do not assume lazyness!

Comment: @RomanC, No i don't have both methods - I have either the isValid() or the getValid(). I know the getValid() will work, but i'm wondering if the isValid() will work too. I would also like to see some official documentation on which methods can be invoked and to get the data and in whch order struts2 will search for them. (for example, will get always precede is?)

Comment: @user1884155: S2 uses OGNL. Read about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will call either `isValid()` or `getValid()` if one exist. If both methods exist which one will be called is not guaranteed by the Java reflection API. See [`Class#getDeclaredMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29). Also Struts2 internally uses method caching, so the first one gets into cache will be used for the next time. So, use one of this methods to access properties.